# What does "exposure" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

They added that some consumer-sector stocks offer effective **exposure** not just to emerging-market economic growth, but also to the burgeoning consumer class's spending growth.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/12/21/mark-mobius-this-is-how-to-play-emerging-markets-in-2017.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Exposure* in this context refers to the opportunity for investment in the market sectors specified.

> > *the act of investing in something:
> >     exposure to sth Her clients wanted more exposure to the energy and real estate sectors.*

However exposure in financial terms can also refer to risk:

> > *the risk of losing money, for example through a loan or investment, or the amount of money that might be lost:
> >     exposure to sth The bank had relatively little exposure to subprime mortgages, which are issued to people with weak credit histories.
> >     If they do walk away from the deal their total exposure is around £40 million.*

Or in marketing:

> > *the amount of public attention that someone or something, especially an advertisement or product, receives:
> >     The overall winner is guaranteed lots of media exposure.
> >     get/gain exposure The product is being advertised to bloggers with the hope of getting more exposure.*

All these examples come directly from *http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exposure*